# Type "myadtype" is not supported in amp-ad

Tags: amp-html

I'm using an `<amp-ad>` tag to serve ads to a site. I'm using the `remote.html` file to specify a custom ad type. It worked like charm for month. Now, about 2 weeks ago, it just stopped working. Nothing changed on our side. It fails even on a blank site. The error is:

> Type "myadtype" is not supported in amp-ad.

I was searching for any changes in the AMP template but could not find any.
What the hell could cause the problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to an example page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't also see any references related to your error. I suggest to [check the supported attributes](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors) for `amp-ad` tag in the [AMP validator spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii). You can also check on this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3133).